# How to Store Array Data Using Ionic Native Storage?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm planning to use ionic native storage to store some translation history, whenever there's a word being translated. The translation action (date, translate word) will be store in the ionic native storage, and when I open history page, a list of translation history will be shown.

Here's the most basic code I got from the ionic official website:

```
export class HomePage {
  DataArray: Array<string> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: Storage) {

  }
  // set a key/value
  setData(){
  this.storage.set('age', 'Max');
  }
  // Or to get a key/value pair
  getData(){
  this.storage.get('age').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your age is', val);
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `getItem` and `SetItem`

```
export class HomePage {
  DataArray: Array<string> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: NativeStorage) {

  }
  // set a key/value
  setData(){
  this.storage.setItem('keyOfData', JSON.stringify(DataArray));
  }
  // Or to get a key/value pair
  getData(){
  this.storage.getItem('keyOfData').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your age is', JSON.parse(val));
  });
}
}
```

the refrence [Ionic native storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/)

Comment: Do u get what i meant? i want to get an array of Data, not a single data.
 Please read my question. :)

Comment: @RongZhao no you can use array , i update the answer so you can use the array to store and restore

Comment: Can i have more detail on JSON.stringify(DataArray). how the data is being write into array list

Comment: this `DataArray` can be your array that hold the data , when store the value to storage make it in a string format and when retrive it parse it back to json to became an array again so you can use it anywhere in the app.

Comment: sorry. i still dont get it. could u make a sample for DataArray code how array is being store.

Comment: check a sample here
https://github.com/TeamClouders/ionic-2-native-storage-demo/blob/master/app/pages/home/home.ts