# Push new element to existing key in native storage - Ionic Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-nativestorage

I'm able to save in the native storage an array in a page and get it in another page.

Function to save data in one page (without leaving this page, I can push new elements and they are properly store):

```
saveWordStorage (OrWord,TrWord){

  this.originalWordDataArray.push(OrWord);
  this.translatedWordDataArray.push(TrWord);

  this.natStorage.setItem("originalWord",JSON.stringify(this.originalWordDataArray))
    .then(
      () => console.log('Stored item!'),
      error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
  this.natStorage.setItem("translatedWord",JSON.stringify(this.translatedWordDataArray))
    .then(
      () => console.log('Stored item!'),
      error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
}
```

the function to get data in the other page:

```
getData(){
    this.natStorage.getItem('originalWord').then((val) => {
      this.originalWordDataArray = JSON.parse(val);

      this.natStorage.getItem('translatedWord').then((val) => {
         this.translatedWordDataArray = JSON.parse(val);
         this.joinArray(this.originalWordDataArray,this.translatedWordDataArray);
      });

    });

  }
```

The problem is when I want to add more elements in the same key after navigating to other pages. I mean, save some elements in the page "A", then navigate trough other pages and go back to the page "A" and save more elements. It only stores the elements added in the last page "A".

I've tried getting the array first from de storage, push the new elements and set it again but without success (basically, join the previous functions):

```
getData(OrWord,TrWord){

  this.natStorage.getItem('originalWord').then((val) => {
    this.originalWordDataArray = JSON.parse(val);
    this.originalWordDataArray.push(OrWord);

    this.natStorage.getItem('translatedWord').then((val) => {
       this.translatedWordDataArray = JSON.parse(val);
       this.translatedWordDataArray.push(TrWord);

       this.natStorage.setItem("originalWord",JSON.stringify(this.originalWordDataArray))
         .then(
           () => console.log('Stored item!'),
           error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
       );
       this.natStorage.setItem("translatedWord",JSON.stringify(this.translatedWordDataArray))
         .then(
           () => console.log('Stored item!'),
           error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
       );
    });
  });
}
```

I'm using `import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';`

Comment: Not the answer, but I don't think you need to stringify and parse json each time you read and write data, you can just store the raw json object.

Comment: What I'm storing in the native storage is an array and I've read here in SO that it was needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473329/how-to-store-array-data-using-ionic-native-storage

Comment: I see, but as I remember I have done it without stringify in ionic. Take a look at the documentation. They have done it in the example. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/